# ntoskrnl High CPU usage in Windows 10 64 Bit

Tags: windows-10, cpu, cpu-usage, window, ntoskrnl.exe

Does anyone experiencing high usage of CPU because of nroskrnl.exe ?
It constantly use 10% of my CPU even in idle position.

I've done

1. adwcleaner
2. Clean boot
3. Malwarebytes

And this still happened. The process happened whenever I sync google and even after tried clean device from chrome this still happened. Anyone know how to remove this ?

Additional process explorer : https://i.stack.imgur.com/90M1X.jpg

Comment: Have you tried opening Services and stopping Windows Search? If this is the culprit, most times it is. You can disable this and are still able to do "Search" items on the computer. There are a few items which you may disable to get better perfomance. You might want to have a look at Black Viper's site (goto Windows 10 Services) blackviper.com

Comment: I just did, and still no luck - sadly :/

Comment: It is a longshot, but you might have a look at this site: https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/system-ntoskrnl-exe-high-memory-or-cpu-usage-in-windows-10/ (there are a few ads there), __I don't recommend using__ Driver Easy software.

Comment: The process in question belongs to the Windows kernel, so depending on the number of peripherals your PC has, it's normal for the ntoskrnl.exe to burn a few CPU cycles here and there. You can *try* to lower its priority with third-party tools like Process Explorer or Process Hacker (if you run them as admin), but there's a good chance it won't work. Now, if this process peaks at, say, 50% CPU *all the time*, then you can say you've got a real problem, but 10% from time to time, not really. How high are your Interrupts? If they too peak at 10-15% and stay there for some time, it's hardware.

Comment: It's always 8-15% on my end

Comment: You mean your Interrupts are constantly around 8-15%?

Comment: The CPU usage of the exe, not iterrupt - sorry

The interrupt is around 2-5%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :

It's regarding the switch in the HDD Caddy